# what causes hypoxia in Covid19?

Tags: covid-19, thrombosis, hypoxia

What is known right now about the causes of hypoxia in Covid19 infection ?
Does it comes from thrombosis formation in lung vessels ? And/or because of damage of lung alveoli by viral replication ? Or maybe totally distinct mechanisms ?

Comment: More like all of the above. https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2020/11/201119153946.htm